# Joining threads recursively in Prolog

Tags: multithreading, swi-prolog

I would like to create a variable number of threads in Prolog and make the main thread wait for all of them.

I have tried to make a join for each one of them in the predicate but it seems like they are waiting one for the other in a sequential order.
I have also tried storing the ids of the threads in a list and join each one after but it still isn't working.
In the code sample, I have also tried passing the S parameters in thread_join in the recursive call.

```
thr1(0):-!.
thr1(N):-
        thread_create(someFunction(N),Id, []),
        thread_join(Id, S),
        N1 is N-1,
        thr1(N1).
```

I expect the N predicates to overlap results when doing some print, but they are running in a sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the calls to your `someFunction/1` predicate succeed faster than the time it takes to create the next thread, which is a relatively heavy process as SWI-Prolog threads are mapped to POSIX threads. Thus, to actually get overlapping results, the computation time of the thread goals must exceed thread creation time. For a toy example of accomplishing that, see:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/threads/sync